# How long was Rey training with Luke?

Tags: star-wars

I was talking with some of my friends and we all had very different opinions on how long Rey was on the island with Luke. **Is there a definitive answer anywhere, or context in the film that I may have missed that hints to how long this training is?** Even though it runs parallel to some scenes with the resistance, it seems likely that Rey was on the island before those scenes started, since we see them sleep multiple times while the resistance scenes appear to be much faster.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177363/how-much-time-did-rey-spend-here?rq=1